# Getting "Script invoked too many times per second" when running script in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, spreadsheet

I have this scheduling application I implemented 4 years ago using Google Spreadsheets. It creates a schedule (or passport) for a science fair. Last year, to make it easier to understand, I created a simple script that looked up the room location to add to the activity:

```
function getRoom(project, map) {
  for (var i=0; i < map.length; i++) {
      if (map[i][0] == project)
          return(map[i][1]);
  }
  return("Not Found");
}
```

The Script is invoked close to 300 times on the worksheet as there are close to 40 schedules with 7 activities each. This worked fine till last year, started getting this error as I prepare the schedules for this year's science fair.

What quotas are this?

Comment: You have simply passed two parameters into the function. Nothing clear from that snippet about what external APIs you have used. Quota is there for APIs for example URLFetch, No. of document create etc.

Comment: I am getting the error on script execution there are NO external APIs - just opened the spreadsheet this morning and it run through completion. There is a quota of sorts associated with those simple script invocations. What is that quota would be good to know, to plan around.

Comment: How is this script called?  Is it a custom function?

Comment: Yes the invocations are within the same spreadsheet from other cells - nothing fancy - The spreadsheet loaded the next day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't posted relevant code nor the actual error so I'll give a generic answer.
1) Read the apps script docs on how to write efficient gas code.
2) optimize often called functions. For example the map you showed could be rebuilt as a hash indexed by project.
2) if that still fails probably means you are running into a time quota since scripts can't run over 6minutes. If so you need to rewrite the code so it can process by parts and remember where it stopped so it can continue from there on next run. Run it manually until it completes all tasks or use a time trigger to run.

Comment: All good suggestions, I went back the next day and the spreadsheet run through completion without any errors.  I will revisit this next year and implement at least the hash maps - thanks